# ¿Cómo puedo traducir uns columna de un dataframe de español a inglés en Python?

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, idioma

Muy buenas, me gustaría traducir una columna de un dataframe de español a inglés en Python pero no sé cómo. Gracias.

Adjunto el código que he insertado y el error que me sale.

```
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()  
translated = translator.translate(df_pr['transcript'], lang_src='es', lang_tgt='en')  
print(translated)
```

El error que me sale es este:
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

He probado también con google_trans_new pero también me aparece erorr.
Al ser un dataframe muy grande, traducirlo a mano me resultada inviable.

Comment: Podrías agregar lo que has intentado hacer o lo que investigaste por favor? Así nos probarás que no pides que te hagamos la tarea. Por cierto, hay un modulo que se comunica con el traductor de google y devuelve todo traducido: [googletrans](https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/). Sin embargo, ten cuidado, un programa encargado de traducir texto comete más errores de traducción que una persona (por ejemplo modismos que se toman de manera literal)

Comment: hola, perdna, ya he editado mi pregunta y ahí tienes la información. gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece ser un error interno del modulo googletrans.

Mientras intentaba dar una respuesta, probé con googletrans y google-trans-new y ninguno de los dos me funcionaron. Entonces busqué un tutorial en google y me encontré con esto: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-translate-text-with-python-9d203139dcf5

En ese tutorial usan un modulo llamado deep-translator. Ese si me funcionó para dar una respuesta.

Este modulo se puede instalar con pip:

```
pip install deep-translator
```

---

###### Código

El siguiente código me ha funcionado:

```
from deep_translator import GoogleTranslator
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([("hola mundo",),
                   ("color del mar",)],
                  columns=("transcript",))

# creamos el objeto que nos permitirá hacer la traducción
translator = GoogleTranslator(source="es", target="en")

# Usamos el método apply de las series en pandas para aplicar a cada valor de la serie una función.
# Esta función será el método translate del objeto translator.
# Luego, reemplazamos la columna original por la modificada
df.transcript = df.transcript.apply(translator.translate)

print(df)
```

###### Produce

```
         transcript
0       Hello World
1  color of the sea
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta, me ha sido de gran ayuda!!